# Supremum in well orderings

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Problem *x7.27 from Moschovakis' textbook is asking to define a definite operation $\sup \mathscr E $, such that for every family $\mathscr E$ of well-ordered sets, $\sup \mathscr E$ has the following properties:

- $\sup \mathscr E$ is a well ordered set
- If $U\in \mathscr E$, then $U \leq_o \sup \mathscr E$
- If $W$ is a well ordered set and for each $U\in \mathscr E$, $U\leq_o W$ then $\sup \mathscr E\leq_o W$

($A\leq_o B$ means that $A$ is isomorphic (in the sense of well orders) to some initial segment of $B$)

Apparently, one way to do this is to use the fact that any well ordering is isomorphic to an ordinal, and then one can take $\sup \mathscr E$ to be the union of the corresponding ordinals in $\mathscr E$. But how to do this without invoking this fact?

(In case it matters -- the previous problem in the textbook was to define $\inf \mathscr E$, and the hint was to look for $\inf \mathscr E$ in the initial segments of $\chi(\bigcup \mathscr E)$ where $\chi(A)$ associates to each set $A$ a well ordered set $\chi(A)$ such that $\chi(A)\not\leq_c A$ (Hartogs' Theorem); $\leq_c$ means "less in size", i.e., "injects into". For this problem, there aren't hints.)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the same proof works without using ordinals:

Define a proper initial segment of a well-ordering to be an initial segment that isn't the entire well-ordering.

Let $\,\mathscr S\,$ be the collection of all proper initial segments of members of $\,\mathscr E.$

The members of $\,\mathscr S\,$ are well-ordered structures -- each one is an ordered pair $\langle W, \lt_W\rangle,$ with its components being the underlying set and its accompanying order relation.

> ***Note**: An alternative way of setting this up is to let $\,\mathscr S\,$
> be the disjoint union $\;\bigsqcup \mathscr E = \{\langle a, W\rangle
>  \mid a\in W \text{ and }W \in \mathscr E\}$ of all the members of
> $\mathscr E.$  We would then use $\langle a, W\rangle$ in the argument below instead of the
> proper initial segment $\{x \mid x \lt_W a\}$ of $W.$  But, even though that seems more natural, it ends up being a little bit messier notationally.*

Define an equivalence relation on $\,\mathscr S\,$ by setting $$\langle W, \lt_W\rangle \sim \langle W', \lt_{W'}\rangle$$ iff $$\langle W, \lt_W\rangle \text{ and } \langle W', \lt_{W'}\rangle\text{ are isomorphic well-orderings.}$$

Now define $\,\mathsf{sup}\;\mathscr E\,$ to be the quotient $\,\mathscr S\, / \sim,\,$ and denote the equivalence class of $\langle W, \lt_W\rangle$ by $[ W, \lt_W].$

Finally, define an ordering $\prec$ on $\,\mathsf{sup}\;\mathscr E,$ by specifying that

$$[W, \lt_W]\prec [W', \lt_{W'}]$$

iff

$$\langle W, \lt_W \rangle\,\text{ is shorter than }\,\langle W', \lt_{W'}\rangle.$$

You can check that $\prec$ is well-defined and has the required properties.

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming "shorter than" means "isomorphic to an initial segment of", right? I might be having trouble verifying properties 2 and 3. For example, for 2, let $U\in \mathscr E$.  What needs to be proved is that $U$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $\sup \mathscr E$. On the intuitive level, we should use that $\sup \mathscr E$ contains the equivalence class of $U$. But this equivalence class isn't an initial segment...

Comment: Yes, by "shorter than", I meant "isomorphic to a proper initial segment of".   To prove these, you should be able to use the fact that, given any two well-orderings $A$ and $B,$ exactly one of $"A\text{ is shorter than }B," B\text{ is shorter than }A,"$ or $"A$ is isomorphic to $B"$ holds.

Comment: But this trichotomy works if we are "inside" the set of equivalence classes $\sup \mathscr E$. I thought in the second point, the problem is to show that something "outside" $\sup \mathscr E$ is isomoprhic to something "inside" $\sup \mathscr E$.

Comment: These are all well-orderings, so the law of trichotomy applies to all of them.  Another useful fact is that the isomorphism of a well-ordering with an initial segment of another well-ordering is unique.  So, for the third bullet point for instance, if we have a well-ordering $W$ such that for each $U\in \mathscr E$, $U\leq_o W,$ then all the isomorphisms of the various sets $U$ with initial segments of $W$ must cohere, so you can piece them together into an isomorphism from $\mathsf{sup} \,\mathscr E$ to some initial segment of $W$ (or possibly all of $W).$